# Installing on WLS2 - error: experimental Nix feature 'nix-command' is disabled

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, nix

I am completely green here. I'm following the instructions laid out in https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/WindowsWSL.html to setup my windows environment for cohort 3 of the pioneer program and having issues.  I've successfully completed steps 1-7 (in the link above), but when I do Step 8, which is ...

nix build -f default.nix plutus.haskell.packages.plutus-core.components.library

I get ...

error: experimental Nix feature 'nix-command' is disabled; use '--extra-experimental-features nix-command' to override

Where do I add that flag in the nix build command?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously there was another ***plutus*** repository, now they made an update with another name ***plutus-apps***, the execution of the command must be updated so that it points to that reference of the ***plutus-apps*** project

nix --extra-experimental-features nix-command build -f default.nix plutus-apps.haskell.packages.plutus-core.components.library

Comment: This worked for my macOS Monterey 2015 Quad i7 setup.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Think I have resolved it.

nix --extra-experimental-features nix-command build -f default.nix plutus.haskell.packages.plutus-core.components.library

Answer (score 0):

I was a little bit on the tutorial and just started setting the environment. Sorry for that indeed.
I get the following error when i try to build plutus with nix command
error: getting status of /home/user/default.nix: no such file or directory
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

it's showing the following error in my installation:
error: getting status of: '/home/user/default.nix': no such file or directory
Please help is needed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).